# Adding "Remind me later" option in Android notification

Tags: android, mobile-development

I am working on a simple Water Reminder app. One of the final things that are left to implement is adding "Remind me later" option when the reminder notification pops. I've searched in many similar questions and articles but I didn't find solution. The thing is that I dont even know what i'm supposed to do...Start some activity, or send something to broadcast receiver or something else. I don't even know how to start trying different approaches. I will be very thankfull if someone helps me! Below is the code. What can I add to the code to implement this function?

```
public class ReminderManager {

public void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(Constants.PATH_TO_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel
                (Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "WaterReminderChannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel for Water Reminder");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}

public void setReminder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentForBroadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + MainActivity.reminderTime, pendingIntentForBroadcast);
}



public class ReminderBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    if (MainActivity.reminderTime > 0 && !MainActivity.dayFinished) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(Constants.PATH_TO_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.water)
                .setContentTitle("Water Reminder")
                .setContentText("It's time to drink something!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe the simplest way to handle this is to use Notification “action buttons.”  See https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Your information helped me to solve the problem. I've made it and want to share my code because it's very simple and maybe will save someone's time instead of searching alot of complicated solutions like I did.

So, below is the code that set alarm for specified by the user time, then after that time occurs the BroadcastReceiver gets triggered even when the phone is in idle state thanks to "AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle" (works for older and newer Android versions). Then the receiver checks by which action is triggered - SNOOZE or REMINDER. If it's SNOOZE, it calls the setReminder() method of my custom ReminderManager class to reset the alarm and then calls notificationManager.cancelAll() to remove the previous notification banner. If it's REMINDER then it calls the showNotification() method which build the notification and show it to the user (I don't find the need to build the notification before the time when the AlarmManager is set to trigger the receiver).

In my ReminderManager class I have createNotificationChannel() method which is needed for newer Android versions and I call it in onCreate of MainActivity. The setReminder() method is called from places that it needs the reminder to be set (when the user sets notification and from the BroadcastReciever as described above) and the showNotification() method is called from BroadcastReciever as described above.

```
public class BroadcastReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ReminderManager reminderManager = new ReminderManager(context);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.SNOOZE_ACTION)) {
        reminderManager.setReminder();
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.REMINDER_ACTION)) {
        reminderManager.showNotification();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ReminderManager {

private final Context context;

public ReminderManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void createNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel
                (Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "WaterReminderChannel",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setSound
                (RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), audioAttributes);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel for Water Reminder");

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}

public void setReminder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(Constants.REMINDER_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentForBroadcast =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + MainActivity.reminderTime, pendingIntentForBroadcast);
}

public void showNotification() {
    Intent maniActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent mainActivityPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, maniActivityIntent, 0);

    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiver.class);
    snoozeIntent.setAction(Constants.SNOOZE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.water)
            .setContentTitle("Water Reminder")
            .setContentText("It's time to drink something!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(mainActivityPendingIntent)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm, "Remind me later", snoozePendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}